# Fastest Layout inside of ScrollView for a large Numbers of ImageViews/ImageButtons

Tags: java, android, android-layout

my App hast some Problems with many Images inside of a ScrollView. I've used an TableLayout with Up to 44 tableRows with 3 ImageViews in each row. While First opening, The Activity loads 3-4s, after that its next opening is a little Bit faster, Like 2s.

Is there a better Layout solution? I've tried GridLayout inside that scrollView, but it dosnt make a big difference, at least it dosnt feel that way. Any Tips or suggestions? Im new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

The best layout is constrainlayout , but make sure you haven't made the recycleview too much nested , because then it will take too long in OnMessure method.
Just make simple view hierarchy.